# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer'.'

Tags: maui

I am getting below exception when I change the mode of my application.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer'.'

I didn't get a clear idea why this is happening. I will share the code of mode change.

When change mode I call a WeakReferenceMessenger like below:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new ModeChangeMessage("modechanged"));
```

Then I subscribe it on my previous page like below:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ModeChangeMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    if (m.Value == "modechanged")
    {
        SetMode();
    }
});
```

Adding the remaining codes below: SetMode is calling light and dark mode functions and from there the it calling the settings function. The options of settings page are handled on settings function and I have added the listview xaml code. I didn't get a clear idea about the issue, that's why I have added all the related code.

```
private void SetMode()
{
    try
    {
        string mode = Preferences.Default.Get("mode", "light");
        if (mode == "light")
        {
            LightMode();
        }
        else if (mode == "dark")
        {
            DarkMode();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + e);
        LightMode();
    }
}

private void DarkMode()
{
    try
    {
        settings_layout.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#434343");
        settings_stack.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#434343");
        settingslistview.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#434343");
        username_label.TextColor = Colors.White;
        SetSettingsItems();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
    }
}

private void LightMode()
{
    try
    {
        settings_layout.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
        settings_stack.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
        settingslistview.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
        username_label.TextColor = Colors.Black;
        SetSettingsItems();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
    }
}

public void SetSettingsItems()
{
    try
    {
        settingList.Clear();
        settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option 1", BGColor = Color.FromArgb("#e4e4e4"), TextColor = Colors.Black, ImageSource = "ic_black_right_arrow_xx.png" });
        settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option 2", BGColor = Color.FromArgb("#e4e4e4"), TextColor = Colors.Black, ImageSource = "ic_black_right_arrow_xx.png" });
        settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option 3", BGColor = Color.FromArgb("#e4e4e4"), TextColor = Colors.Black, ImageSource = "ic_black_right_arrow_xx.png" });
        settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option 4", BGColor = Color.FromArgb("#e4e4e4"), TextColor = Colors.Black, ImageSource = "ic_black_right_arrow_xx.png" });
        settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option 5", BGColor = Color.FromArgb("#e4e4e4"), TextColor = Colors.Black, ImageSource = "ic_black_right_arrow_xx.png" });
        settingslistview.ItemsSource = settingList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
    }
}


<ListView   
    x:Name="settingslistview"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    SelectionMode="None"
    SeparatorColor="#cecece"
    ItemTapped="SettingTapped"
    SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Frame
                        HasShadow="False"
                        Padding="8"
                        CornerRadius="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=30}"
                        BorderColor="#bdbdbd"
                        Margin="5"
                        BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}">

                        <StackLayout 
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Margin="5,0,5,0"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Title}"
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"/>

                            <Image 
                                Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Frame.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>40</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>60</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>40</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Frame.HeightRequest>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.Footer>
        <Label/>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official document about the Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame) said:

> The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement. For more information, see Border and Shadow.

So you can use the [Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border) instead of the Frame.

In addidtion, you can also refer to this issue about [ListView with ObservableCollection issue during scrolling (ObjectDisposedException)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11323).

And if you still want to use frame, you can put the frame in the grid, such as:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Frame
                        HasShadow="False"
                        Padding="8"
                        CornerRadius="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=30}"
                        BorderColor="#bdbdbd"
                        Margin="5"
                        BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}">
```